# Upgraded Orchard CMS from 1.6 to 1.8 now theme doesn't appear

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I recently upgraded from 1.6 to 1.8. I am working with the source code so I have the entire src directory. I downloaded 1.8, then proceeded to copy over my modules, and TheThemeMachine folder from under Orchard.Web (I have customized this theme). I then copied over my App_Data folder and ran the project. The site fired up fine, and looks to be pulling content from the database so everything is OK there, however, it doesn't look to be using the theme I copied over (TheThemeMachine). The current theme setting looks to be stored in the database, so does anybody know why it wouldn't be loading the theme I had selected? Is there something I missed in that upgrade process?

Comment: Check your logs. The theme doesn't compile or load for some reason. Is there code in your theme?

Comment: Upon further review I had missed a 1.7.2 upgrade point about setting the super user as admin (I guess this changed?). Once I did this, I got to the dashboard, re-selected the theme and everything works now.